# Use existing malloc best fit algorithm to manage custom preallocated memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I’m writing custom allocators and after a couple of basic allocators, I’m at a point where I need a more generalized allocator. Just like malloc...

So do I have to write my own allocator with its own best fit algorithm or can I just hint malloc the rough amount of allocations I’ll make so that it can preallocate some amount of memory?

Alternatively I could preallocate the memory myself and give the buffer to malloc to manage.

Strictly speaking I know malloc deals with OS and allocates and commits virtual memory etc. I’m talking about the algorithm that intelligently places new allocations inside a memory pool. As far as I know you can only get pages of virtual memory so the algorithm that manages that virtual page is in there somewhere.

Do I really need to write my own best fit algorithm where I could use Malloc which is written by people who are a lot smarter than I am?

Comment: C or C++ ?  Choose one.

Comment: Sorry it’s C++, I’ll edit the post.

Comment: Have you profiled and found `malloc` to be a bottleneck? If not I'd stick with the default `malloc`. And before writing anything custom I'd try [`jemalloc`](http://jemalloc.net/).

Comment: What's wrong with `new []` ?